# Retornar valores de duas colunas de tabelas diferentes

Tags: mysql

Tenho a tabela ALUNOS e a tabela PROFESSORES, há mais professores que alunos, queria realizar uma consulta que traga alunos em uma coluna e professores em outra e não todos em uma só.

Todos em uma coluna ficou assim:

```
SELECT PK_PROFESSORES AS CÓDIGO_ALUNO_PROFESSOR, NOME, IF(PK_PROFESSORES != NULL, 'ALUNO', 'PROFESSOR') AS VÍNCULO
FROM PROFESSORES
UNION 
SELECT PK_ALUNO, NOME, IF(PK_ALUNO != NULL, 'PROFESSOR', 'ALUNO') AS VÍNCULO
FROM ALUNOS
```

Há a possibilidade de trazer cada um em uma coluna?

Comment: Só por curiosidade por que você faz isso dos `IF`?

Comment: Como é o relacionamento das suas tabelas?

Comment: Porque como retornou tudo em uma coluna, eu queria diferenciar os alunos de professores, o IF é uma nova coluna que diz se é professor ou aluno. hehehe

Comment: Professores e alunos não estão relacionados.

Comment: E por que não faz um produto cartesiano? Exemplo `SELECT * FROM ALUNOS, PROFESSORES`

Comment: Retornou dados repetidos, mesmo usando o distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui fazer aqui, veja se é o que você precisa

```
SELECT PROFESSOR.NOME, ALUNO.NOME FROM 
( 
  SELECT @rownum_p:=@rownum_p+1 AS ROW_NUM, PROFESSORES.NOME FROM PROFESSORES, (SELECT @rownum_p:=0) r
)  PROFESSOR
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT @rownum_a:=@rownum_a+1 AS ROW_NUM, ALUNOS.NOME FROM ALUNOS, (SELECT @rownum_a:=0) r
) ALUNO ON PROFESSOR.ROW_NUM=ALUNO.ROW_NUM
```

Basicamente criei um "ID FALSO" e vinculei eles.

### [SqlFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36059/11/0)